# How to sort two lists quickly in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have two lists:

```
List<Object1> list1
List<Object2> list2
```

- list1 object contains an id.
- list2 object contains a perId.

I want to remove from list1 all the objects that match

```
Object1.id = Object2.perId.
```

Does anyone have a method to do that quickly?

Comment: Show your efforts first..

Comment: We can help you finding a problem when you are stuck. We aren't here for doing your job.

Comment: Check this link
[enter link description here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100973/merge-two-lists-in-java-and-sort-them-using-object-property-and-another-conditio)

Comment: You can do list1.remove(list2) and then calls Arrays.sort method to sort remaining entries

Comment: What do you mean by "quickly"? Are you looking for a specific level of efficiency?

Answer (score 2):

Collect all `perId`s from `Object2`s into a `HashSet` and then filter out from `list1` all elements whose id is in that set:

```
Set<Integer> ids = list2.stream()
        .map(x -> x.perId)
        .collect(toCollection(HashSet::new));
List<Object1> result = list1.stream()
        .filter(x -> !ids.contains(x.id))
        .collect(toList());
```

This assumes that your id is of type `int`, so you might want to change it accordingly.

This solution does not require your two classes `Object1` and `Object2` to have `equals()` or `hashCode()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting the lists quickly in Java using Collections.

```
Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);
```

If you're comparing the values after sorting:

```
for (Object1 o : list1) {
  for (Object2 p : list2) {
     if ((o.getSomeValue()).equals(p.getSomeValue())) list1.remove(o);
  }
}
```

Time complexity would be m x n for this. (where m is length of list1 and n is length of list2)

If you care about time complexity. A faster way would be looping through list2 and add each value to a HashSet. Then loop through list1 separately and compare the values with the values we had in HashSet. Basically it should look like this but you have to make progress on it with your code.

```
HashSet<T> hSet = new HashSet<T>(); 

for (Object2 p : list2) {
   if (!hSet.contains(p.getSomeValue())) {
      hSet.add(p);
   } 
}

for (Object1 o : list1) {
   if (hSet.contains(o.getSomeValue())) {
      list1.remove(o);
   } 
}
```

Time complexity =  m + n (where m is length of list1 and n is length of list2)

Comment: `if (set does not contain p) add p to the set` is what any `Set` implementation does internally and you don't need this if statement, you can just call `add` with all objects.